# More clicks but the client said he didn't get all of this clicks!

Tags: google-ads

I have a client that I was running for him a search ad, to make customers **call his phone number**, in my Adwords dashboard *the phone number was clicked 176 times during the last month (1-31 December)*, **the problem is the client said that it is ONLY (7 people) call him during this period!!!**

I just wonder is that may occur or what? I don't understand why he is said that, so if anyone has such this situation tell me what to do?

you could see the screenshots from my Adwords below

[image: my Adwords dahboard]
[image: call extension]

Comment: "...didn't get all of this clicks!" - Presumably you mean "calls" (as stated throughout the rest of the question)? Although "clicks" and "calls" are two quite different metrics. "Clicks" is bound to be much higher than actual phone "calls" - isn't it?! I'm not really sure what the question is here?

Comment: I am sorry for this misunderstanding, yes I mean calls you could see in the screenshots, I have 176 clicks on the phone number, but the client said that he get 7 phone calls!

Comment: How are you measuring the clicks?   If it is a link with a `tel:` URL, I'm not sure how you would have a tracking code on that.

Comment: Your screenshot shows 176 clicks but 0 conversion. 

Did you configure Call conversion well? 

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6095882?hl=en 

Clicks and Calls are different since users can click and close immediatly without ringing your client.